# How do I get the most recent records based on as of date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
+------------------------------------+
|     Number  Name     Date          |
+------------------------------------+
| 1   1050    Name1    2015-01-01    |
| 2   1051    Name2    2015-04-27    |
| 3   1057    Name3    2015-04-27    |
+------------------------------------+
```

How should I get the most recent records? I've tried something like:

```
SELECT number, name, MAX(DATE) AS recent_date
FROM Recent_Table
HAVING recent_date < '2015-05-19'
GROUP BY number, name
```

I'm expecting to get the most recent records but instead I'm getting all three because of my having clause. Is there a way to work around this while still keeping my `having`? Thanks.

Expected output would be:

```
  1051    Name2    2015-04-27
  1057    Name3    2015-04-27
```

Comment: can you add expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select number, name, date
from Recent_Table
where Date = (SELECT MAX(DATE) AS recent_date
              FROM Recent_Table
              WHERE DATE < '2015-05-19')
```

there is problem with `name` column not with `having` clause. I think you don't need `having`.

**[Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92267/2/0) demo**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
number,
name,
DATE AS recent_date
FROM Recent_Table
WHERE DATE = (SELECT MAX(t2.DATE)
                 FROM Recent_Table t2
                 WHERE t2.number = t1.number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT number, name, MAX(DATE) AS recent_date
FROM Recent_Table
WHERE DATE <= MAX(DATE)
GROUP BY number, name
```

Will return values that are the latest entries

Comment: `WHERE DATE <= MAX(DATE)` is not valid

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess

```
 SELECT number, name
 FROM   Recent_Table
 WHERE recent_date >= (Select Max(Date) FROM Recent_Table)
```

Comment: I think you mean `WHERE Date = (Select Max(Date) FROM Recent_Table)`

Comment: or this variant its the same

Comment: not really. you'll get an error `Column 'recent_date' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

Comment: oh ok sorry i dont have environment to chek it, i will update